# How can I save the whole body of Webview in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, webview, vscode-extensions

In the [Webview Api Guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#persistence), in the Persistance section, it is shown how to persist a JSON serializable state object. **But how can I make the whole body of my html code persist in case, the webview loses focus?**

In my extension, I am receiving messages from the vscode extension and updating the Webview by appending `<p>paragraph</p>`
 to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create your webview you can set an option to retain the content on hiding the view, like this:

```
    let panel = window.createWebviewPanel(
        'antlr4-vscode-webview', options.title, ViewColumn.Two, {
            enableScripts: true,
            retainContextWhenHidden: true
        }
    );
```

If you only want to retain a certain DOM node (including the body or even the entire document) you can send a message to your webview and the function handling this message gets the outer HTML from the node and sends that text back to your extension, where it can be saved and later be restored.

In my extension vscode-antlr4 I do that to [export generated SVG content](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/misc/utils.js#L16) (created with D3.js):

```js
function exportToSVG(type, name) {
    // Saving the SVG is delegated to the extension to allow asking the user for a target file.
    const svg = document.querySelectorAll('svg')[0];
    const args = {
        command: "saveSVG",
        name: name,
        type: type,
        svg: svg.outerHTML
    };

    vscode.postMessage(args);
}
```

The code for handling this message is in the [WebviewProvider](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/src/frontend/WebviewProvider.ts#L61) class. The same file also contains the method to send a message to the webview content:

```
protected sendMessage(uri: Uri, args: any): boolean {
    if (this.webViewMap.has(uri.toString())) {
        let [panel, _] = this.webViewMap.get(uri.toString())!;
        panel.webview.postMessage(args);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use `retainContextWhenHidden` because apparently it is slower that `getState()`, `saveState`. Any way to do it using these?